# Genie's GLib TreeSearchFunc delegate

Tags: delegates, genie

I write a code, it is about GLib.Tree. But don't know how to use the search method.

Valadoc has an example for this, and works!

below is my code:

```
[indent = 4]

def cmp (a: string, b: string): int
    return strcmp (a, b)
init
    var t = new Tree of string, string (cmp)
    t.insert ("a", "aaa")
    t.insert ("b", "bbb")

    var needle = "A"
    fun: TreeSearchFunc = def (k)
        return strcmp (k.down(), needle.down())

    var ret = t.search (fun)
```

ERROR!

> error: The name `down' does not exist in the context of`K'

try again:

```
    fun: TreeSearchFunc of string = def (k)
```

ERROR!

> error: 'GTreeSearchFunc' undeclared

TreeSearchFunc Description:

```
public delegate int TreeSearchFunc (K key)
```

If I want to write a TreeSearchFunc delegate?
How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a practical point of view you are implementing a case insensitive search for GLib.Tree. It would probably be better to use the `search_key()` function:

```
[indent = 4]
init
    var tree = new Tree of ( string, string )( cmp )
    tree.insert( "a", "aaa" )
    tree.insert( "b", "bbb" )

    result:string = tree.search_key( case_insensitive_compare, "A" )
    print result

def cmp( a:string, b:string ):int
    return strcmp( a, b )

def case_insensitive_compare ( a:string, b:string ):int
    return strcmp( a.down(), b.down() )
```

As your question specifically asks for a `TreeSearchFunc` delegate then the code would be:

```
[indent = 4]
init
    var tree = new Tree of ( string, string ).full( cmp, free, free )
    tree.insert( "a", "aaa" )
    tree.insert( "b", "bbb" )

    result:string = tree.search( case_insensitive_search_for_a )
    print result

def cmp( a:string, b:string ):int
    return strcmp( a, b )

def case_insensitive_search_for_a ( k:string ):int
    return strcmp( k.down(), "A".down() )
```

A few points to note:

- the `TreeSearchFunc` delegate version has to the have the search term, the "A", inside its scope. The example in Valadoc makes use of a closure, which also includes the enclosing scope, unfortunately you can't do that in Genie yet
- the Valadoc version used `Tree.full`, so I've shown how to do that in the `TreeSearchFunc` delegate version. This was in case you were unsure how parameters of type (generics) are used in Genie

In your example you have rightly tried to use a closure in Genie by assigning it to a variable. This is only available in the development version of Vala so you must have downloaded and compiled the latest Vala. This should become available when Vala 0.32 is released. If you try and use the same method in Vala you will get the same error. So I think the problem is in the Vala compiler. Currently Genie does not support anonymous functions being defined inside parentheses or braces. If you are interested in adding support take a look at https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=760492

Comment: I want to ask another question about how to use **Tree.full**, but you gave me the answer already!
I have never seen this syntex before. **"new A of (B, C).D (E)"**
Thanks.